# Canvas element drawn with incorrect properties

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

When the `unit.length` reaches its last one, the last `chatbubble` drawn above the character takes the properties of `highlightSelectedCharacter`!

Simply, `chatbubble` ignores all of its styles, and takes everything inside `highlightSelectedCharacter`. If I change lineWidth or the color inside `highlightSelectedCharacter`, so would the last run for `chatbubble`.

When I take `chatbubble` completely out, some other function gets affected the same way.

This only happens when `highlightSelectedCharacter` is turned on (when `characterSelect != -1` returns true).

Also note that `highlightSelectedCharacter();` is outside the loop, so there is no reason why they should affect eachother.

If I comment out `drawChatBubble`, `drawShadow` gets affected now.

```
for (var i = 0; i < unit.length; i++) {
    moveCharacter(i);
    drawShadow(unit[i].position.x, unit[i].position.y);
    drawChatBubble(unit[i].position.x, unit[i].position.y);

    drawCharacter(unit[i]);
}

//Highlight Selected Character
if (characterSelect != -1) {
    highlightSelectedCharacter();
}

function drawChatBubble(positionA, positionB) {
    var centerX = positionA + 45;
    var centerY = positionB;
    var boxSize = 10;

    ctx["canvas"].save();

    ctx["canvas"].fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)';
    ctx["canvas"].strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)';
    ctx["canvas"].lineWidth = 3;

    ctx["canvas"].beginPath();
    ctx["canvas"].moveTo(centerX, centerY);
    ctx["canvas"].lineTo(centerX + boxSize, centerY - boxSize * 2);
    ctx["canvas"].lineTo(centerX + boxSize, centerY - boxSize * 4);
    ctx["canvas"].lineTo(centerX + boxSize * 4, centerY - boxSize * 4);
    ctx["canvas"].lineTo(centerX + boxSize * 4, centerY - boxSize);
    ctx["canvas"].lineTo(centerX + boxSize * 2, centerY - boxSize);
    ctx["canvas"].lineTo(centerX + 0, centerY + 0);
    ctx["canvas"].closePath();
    ctx["canvas"].stroke();
    ctx["canvas"].fill();

    ctx["canvas"].restore();

    ctx["canvas"].drawImage(iconSet, 32 * 7, 32 * 0, 32, 32, centerX + boxSize + 2, centerY - boxSize * 4 + 2, boxSize * 3 - 4, boxSize * 3 - 4);
}

function highlightSelectedCharacter() {
    ctx["canvas"].save();
    ctx["canvas"].strokeStyle = "#00FFFF";
    ctx["canvas"].lineWidth = 2;
    ctx["canvas"].rect(unit[characterSelect].position.x, unit[characterSelect].position.y, 51, 51);
    ctx["canvas"].stroke();
    ctx["canvas"].restore();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "reaches its last one"? can you add a jsfiddle? it would help illustrate the problem

Comment: I'm afraid I can't, it's a lot of code. Say unit.length is 20. 0-18 is perfectly fine - 19 is the last one. I have tried changing unit length as well, always the last one messes up

Comment: you can add a minimal and verifiable example, you don't need to add the whole lot. Otherwise it's a pretty vague question.. good luck

Comment: I don't think I can without exposing the entire code. Isn't there anything that may cross your mind I can try? When `highlightSelectedCharacter()` turns on, that's when it happens

Comment: You seem to have commented out `ctx['canvas'].save()` while still keeping the `ctx['canvas'].restore()` active. This is screwing with your state stack. Uncomment the first one.

Comment: Hi, sorry it wasn't originally commented. I was trying out things. Commenting/uncommenting it made no difference at all. I have also tried emptying my cache

Comment: I think I figured out what's causing the issue. Basically, the `stroke()` inside `highlightSelectedCharacter` is not only drawing the `rect`, but also drawing the last `stroke()`, thus causing the last `bubblechat` appear to change color. It's simple redrawing it! But still have no idea how its happening, nor to fix it